# How to upload a zip file from sdcard using dropbox-android-sync-sdk-1.0

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I need to upload a `zip` file on my `sd card` to `dropbox` using `dropbox-android-sync-sdk-1.0`. i couldn't find any method for upload. i have found methods for create folders and files. (`dbxFs.createFolder()` and `dbxFs.create()`). but unable to find method for upload existing files on `sd card`.

how could i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writeFromExistingFile method on DbxFile allows you to upload existing files:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFile